# How to have a date remain nullable when autopopulating other dates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am extremely new to this and am taking on programming for a job that wasn't supposed to involve programming so please be gentle. :)

This application is in MVC 3 and I have code that works great in making two other dates dependent on the first. However, the first date is nullable. Before I added this code you could create an item without having that field filled in. Now, it blows up if the field is left blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Procedure procedure)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Procedures.Add(procedure);
            if (procedure.Effective != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                procedure.ScheduledReview = procedure.Effective.Value.AddMonths(-1);
                procedure.UserReview = procedure.Effective.Value.AddMonths(-3);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.PossibleProTypes = context.ProTypes;
        ViewBag.PossibleStatus = context.Status;
        ViewBag.PossiblePendingActions = context.PendingActions;
        ViewBag.PossibleOffices = context.Offices;
        return View(procedure);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if (procedure.HasValue)
    {
        procedure.ScheduledReview = procedure.Effective.Value.AddMonths(-1);
        procedure.UserReview = procedure.Effective.Value.AddMonths(-3);
    }
```

A null datetime isn't equal to DateTime.MinValue, so your `if` expression is true, then is probably throwing a NullReferenceException when you try to assign the value using `procedure.Effective.Value`